# input on submit popup lightbox with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need a functionality for my newsletter signup:

When user presses enter there should be a lightbox that appears that says a message.

It's on a WordPress site and until now I have this:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {$("li:has(ul)").addClass("parent");$('.sub-menu li:first-child').addClass("firstchild");}</script>
```

Obviously I've used jQuery also for other purposes.

The newsletter form:

```
<form id="newsletterform"><input type="text" class="input" name="email" value="Subscribe to our newsletter" onfocus="if (this.value=='Subscribe to our newsletter') this.value = ''" onblur="this.value=this.value==''?'Subscribe to our newsletter':this.value;"><input type="submit" class="submit"></form>
```

Curious question:

How can I solve my problem?

Magical word: PLEASE :)

Thank you.

**P.S.: Any other idea/solution? Input form whith jQuery action on submit and implemented in WordPress files.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery ui dialog will come in handy for you. See this [blog](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/) to understand how to use the jquery ui dialog. Lightbox goes only with images...

Comment: thanks. I have tested it on my page and it's not working. possible some conflict, but the popup did not showed up when I clicked the button.

Comment: did you add the jquery ui.js?

Comment: included ui files, added javascript in header, created popupbox div and added the submit button for test. but i need implemented into my wordpress generated code also.